# How to delete certain characters after a pattern using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file containing number of lines formatted like below

```
001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello; Hi:
```

my goal is to clean whatever is after `;;;`. Meaning to delete the following characters `,;()~?`

I know i can do something like `sed 's/[,.;()~?,]//g'`. However if I do that, it would give me something like

```
001_Awav112.680115211Ja Hello Hi
```

However I would like to delete those character only after `;;;` so I would get

```
001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja Hello Hi
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`(where assuming `;;;` occurring one time in lines).

```
awk '
match($0,/.*;;;/){
  laterPart=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[,.:;()~?]/,"",laterPart)
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) laterPart
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/.*;;;/){                     ##Using atch function to match everything till ;;; here.
  laterPart=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)  ##Creating variable laterPart which has rest of the line apart from matched regex part above.
  gsub(/[,.:;()~?]/,"",laterPart)      ##Globally substituting ,.:;()~? with NULL in laterPart variable.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) laterPart ##Printing sub string of matched regex and laterPart var here.
}' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you have multiple occurrences of `;;;` in lines and you want to substitute characters from all fields, after 1st occurrence of `;;;` then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";;;"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/[,.:;()~?,]/,"",$i)}} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Faster than mine as well: 0m0.026s. awk is the real magic hehe. +1

Comment: Hehe, IMHO; but it's not about question shell kind of questions could be handled with awk, sed, bash perl default languages coming in system. That's why different people give different types of solutions which is totally fine IMHO. It could help users who are referring thread in future and they will have plenty of options too. That's why SO given 5 tags to be added :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Changed the title!

Comment: @JirrSawaf, your welcome, happy learning cheers. Since you have changed the title now I have added awk tag now

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
sed ':a; s/\(;;;[^,.:;()~?,]*\)[,.:;()~?,]/\1/; ta' file > newfile
sed ':a; s/\(;;;[^[:punct:]]*\)[[:punct:]]/\1/; ta' file > newfile
```

**Details**

- `:a` sets a label
- `\(;;;[^,.:;()~?,]*\)[,.:;()~?,]` matches and captures into Group 1 a `;;;` substring and then any zero or more chars other than `,.:;()~?,` chars, and then just matches a char from the  `,.:;()~?,` set
- `[^[:punct:]]*` matches any 0 or more chars other than punctuation chars
- `[[:punct:]]` matches any punctuation char
- `\1` is the replacement, the contents of Group 1
- `ta` branches back to `a` label on a successful replacement.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/htewFp):

```sh
s='001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello; Hi:'
sed ':a; s/\(;;;[^,.:;()~?,]*\)[,.:;()~?,]/\1/; ta' <<< "$s"
# => 001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja Hello Hi
sed ':a; s/\(;;;[^[:punct:]]*\)[[:punct:]]/\1/; ta' <<< "$s"
# => 001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja Hello Hi
```

Comment: Never understood `:a` until now. Your solution is quite slower for larger files (7200x `001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello; Hi:`, redirect output to /dev/null). Mine: 0m0.031s, yours: 0m0.086s. +1 however :-)

Answer (score 2):

Didn't read your question correctly, but I've changed it now.

I suggest to make use of `perl` instead, since it has lookup groups.

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/^((?:(?!;;;).)*;;;)|[:,.;\(\)~\?,]/\1/g' file.txt
```

- `^` is the beginning of the line.
- `((?:(?!;;;).)*;;;)` is the string equivalent of `[^;]*`, and makes sure that the *first* `;;;` is found and groups it in `\1`.
- `|[:,\.;\(\)~\?,]` selects the characters `:,.;\(\)~\?,` and denies it in the result. (Thus leaving "Ja" in it).

Comment: `(?:(?!;;;).)*` is not really necessary here. You might as well use `.*?`.

Comment: Fair, but that would take the last `;;;` in the string instead of the first, right?

Comment: Tempered greedy token has no advantage over a lazy dot pattern in cases like this. `.*?` is faster. It matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as *few* as possible.

Comment: Cool to know that `s/^(.*?;;;)|[:,.;\(\)~\?,]/\1/g` works as well :-D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combination of some `sed` commands with

```
echo '001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello; Hi:' |
   sed 's/;;;/;;;\n\r/' |
   sed  '/^\r/ s/[,;():~?]//g' |
   sed -z 's/;;;\n\r/;;;/g'
```

Comment: What the hell. How can yours be the fastest!? 0m0.017s

Answer (score 0):

Different GNU `AWK`-solution:

```
echo "001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello; Hi:" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";;;"}{print $1,gensub(/[,;()~?]/,"","g",substr($0,length($1)+1))}'
```

output:

```
001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello Hi:
```

This assumes your description has precedence over example (only `,;()~?` will be removed). Explanation: I use `;;;` as seperator and output seperator then I `print` 1st column (what is before `;;;`) and get rest by finding its start as length of 1st column plus 1, then remove all specified characters from that part and print it.
If example has precedence over description then you might use `[[:punct:]]` set of characters, namely:

```
echo "001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja. Hello; Hi:" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";;;"}{print $1,gensub(/[[:punct:]]/,"","g",substr($0,length($1)+1))}'
```

will give

```
001_A.wav;112.680;115.211;;;Ja Hello Hi
```